# How to `bundle install` when your Gemfile requires an older version of bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I am in an older Rails project that has a Gemfile. I tried to add a gem to the Gemfile and `bundle install` but got an error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.0) ruby depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0) ruby

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.1.5)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
```

The version of Rails it's using requires bundler ~>1.0.0 but I have 1.1.5 installed and am using it for my other projects. Usually I would use `bundle exec ...` but since this is bundler we are talking about, it's a little more complicated than that. How can I add a gem to my Gemfile and run `bundle install` while using the version of bundler that it requires?

Comment: I guess uninstall 1.1.5 bundler first. Then install 1.0.0. This will fix. Maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 218, accepted):

First you need to install the appropriate version of bundler:

```
% gem install bundler -v '~> 1.0.0'
Successfully installed bundler-1.0.22
```

Then force rubygems to use the version you want ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373128/how-do-i-activate-a-different-version-of-a-particular-gem)):

```
% bundle _1.0.22_ install
```

Comment: Why the heck is this not in the Bundler docs?!?  

Thanks, after wasting more hours than I care to admit your answer finally explained what I needed.

Comment: To go for an exact version these days you will want to use `gem install bundler -v '=1.16.0'`

Comment: Not working now. It cannot force rubygems to use the version which ```bundle _1.0.22_ install``` specified

Comment: I just used this approach and it worked for me @Alec.Zhou . I have both `bundler 2.2.15` and `bundler 2.2.16` installed.

Answer (score 11):

This is what I had to do to get it to work to install with a previous version (2.2.11) of bundler:

```
gem install bundler:2.2.11
bundle _2.2.11_ install
```

Answer (score 4):

The error message `In Gemfile: bundler (~> 1.16)` is a bit inaccurate, since the version number requirement can come from other places, such as the `.gemspec` file, which was the case for me:

```rb
spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.16"
```

Removing the version number from the `.gemspec` file solved the issue for me:

```rb
spec.add_development_dependency "bundler"
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on macOS Mojave. I installed the different version of the bundler gem and uninstall the current version.

`gem install bundler -i '2.0.1'`

`gem uninstall bundler`

Then gives me the option to choose the version to uninstall and I choose the one which is creating the problem.

Comment: Not necessarily a recommended way of doing this. I'd try the accepted answer first, you might have other gems depending on the later versions, and you can run them separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `rvm` to manage your ruby versions consider using [gemsets](https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics) for projects. This way you can install the specific version of bundler needed without having to specify the version each time.

You can confirm your `gemset` is loaded by running `rvm info` in your project directory.

Now you can install the version of bundler you'd like via `gem install bundler -v '~> <VERSION>'`. The next time you need to use bundler just run `bundle`.