# 'require': no such file to load -- rails/cli (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

when I uninstalled bundler 1.6.2 to use 1.0.0 rails crashed. I tried this command:

```
gem uninstall -i /home/mayukh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global bundler -v=1.6.2
```

Please note, I have uninstalled this **globally**

Now, when I run `rails -v` or `rails s` it shows error like this:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- rails/cli (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/rails:7:in `<main>'
```

My ruby version is **ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-linux]**

1. Is it the right way to use/uninstall bundler? or is there any way to switch between bundlers?
2. How to fix this issue and run rails again?

Comment: You should probably try uninstalling all bundler instances, then reinstall the latest one.

Comment: As @tadman said uninstall all bundler options. However is there a particular reason `gem uninstall bundler` wouldn't have sufficed?

Comment: @tadman I tried uninstalling all bundlers with >>gem uninstall bundler   ,and installed 1.0.0, but rails is still not working :(

Comment: Which version of Rails? I'm not sure all of them cope with four year old versions of `bundler`.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall bundle might not be the better solution. If you want to force the bundle version to install something try this (as said in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12093575/2810526)) :

```
bundle _1.0.0_ install
```

But for you current problem, you should do what tadman said. Uninstall all bundle instances and get the lastest one to force the version after.

Hope this help !

Comment: tried bundler install ad uninstalling ...still facing problem with rails start: rails/cli (LoadError)

Comment: Do you use rvm ? If not, it might be a permission access problem. Because you need rx permission where rails is installed.