# issue using gemfile in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some dependency issues with the latest bundler version of "1.9.7". I need bundler version "1.7.3" for this.
I tried specifying the required bundler version as "1.7.3" in my project's Gemfile. But, it isnt working. It is always referring to the latest bundler version thats installed in my PC.

So, how should I specify the required bundler version for my project?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can force a particular version using e.g. `$ bundle _1.7.3_ install`.

See [How to `bundle install` when your Gemfile requires an older version of bundler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092928/how-to-bundle-install-when-your-gemfile-requires-an-older-version-of-bundler)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this version only in this project, I would recommend to create a gemset using rvm and install the version that you want on it.

Here some tips:

```
# rvm gemset create your_project_name
# rvm gemset use your_project_name
# gem install bundle -v '1.7.3'
```