# Gitlab CI/CD Job fails when installing Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, cicd

I want to run the tests after every commit. When installing the bundler, however, the following error message appears: "You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile" although I install version 2.2.5

```
stages:
  - test
test-job:
  stage: test
  image: ruby:2.5.1
  script:
    - gem install bundler -v 2.2.5
    - bundle install
    - bundle exec rails test
```

[image]

Comment: You can since you are installing a specific version of bundler you can also specify that version for bundle commands. See [This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12093575/1978251) for more info

Answer (score 1):

bundler `1.16.6` is included in `ruby:2.5.1` and is used per default as you can see here:

```shell
$ gem list bundler
bundler (2.2.5, 1.16.6, default: 1.16.2)
```

Try this instead:

```yaml
test-job:
  stage: test
  image: ruby:2.5.1
  before_script:
    - gem update --system
  script:
    - bundle install
    - bundle exec rails test
```

Comment: I tried your answer but it doesn't work:
```RubyGems installed the following executables:
 /usr/local/bin/gem
 /usr/local/bin/bundle
 /usr/local/bin/bundler
RubyGems system software updated
$ bundle install
You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
Cleaning up file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1```