# How to use a specific version of CocoaPods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Is it possible to somehow specific the version of CocoaPods I'd like to use when upgrading or installing a Podfile? I've encountered several times where Podfiles work correctly with one version of CocoaPods but not with others.

For example, the syntax I'm looking for is like the following:

```
pod -v 0.34 install
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Since CocoaPods is installed through RubyGems you can use their mechanisms for doing this. As outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373128/how-do-i-activate-a-different-version-of-a-particular-gem) you can do this:

```
pod _0.34.0_ install
```

You can verify this is working with:

```
pod _0.34.0_ --version
```

Also I would *highly* advise against doing this at all. I would definitely recommend you keep CocoaPods up to date and change your Podfile as needed to adapt to new versions. At anytime your old version could stop working as expected if we bump the [minimum version number](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/CocoaPods-version.yml).

Answer (score 16):

the ultimate solution:

1. run a bash script to completely uninstall your current verison (Optinal)

   ```
   for i in $( gem list --local --no-version | grep cocoapods  ); do
       sudo gem uninstall $i;
   done   
   sudo gem uninstall xcodeproj
   ```
2. install a specific verison of CocoaPod

   ```
   gem install cocoapods -v 0.39.0
   ```