# OSX :Making CocoaPods compatible with older version install

Tags: ios, xcode6, cocoapods

I installed CocoaPods (cocoapods-0.37.2) but I need to make sure is  backward­-compatible with version 0.35.0. My question for you is how can I do that?

Here is how installed:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you install CocoaPods through rubygems you can use their infrastructure for this. In this case installing an old version is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20489489/902968). Once you install an old version you'll have both the newer and older installed. This means when you run `pod` it will pick the new one. If you don't want to uninstall `0.37.2` then you'll have to specify which you want to use. That process is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29420456/902968)