# How can I use an older version of Bundler for a Ruby project?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, rbenv

...without uninstalling the latest version.

I'm working on a project that uses Bundler 1.10, but I use Bundler 1.11 for all my other projects. Since this project is on 1.10, whenever I run any `bundle` commands, my `Gemfile.lock` changes due to the different formatting introduced by Bundler 1.11.

The only solution I've found so far is running all my commands like so:

```
bundle _1.10.6_ [command]
```

(from this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4373478/1612744)

Is there a better way? I'm using rbenv, not rvm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up solving this with an alias and a bash function. In my `~/.bashrc`, I added this:

```
versioned_bundle() {
  version_file=${PWD}/.bundle/version
  if [[ -r $version_file ]]; then
    version=$(<$version_file)
    bundle _${version}_ "$@"
  else
    bundle "$@"
  fi
}
alias bundle=versioned_bundle
```

As you can guess from the code, I also added a `version` file to the `.bundle/` directory in my project. That file's contents:

```
1.10.6
```

Whenever I run `bundle`, my shell checks for a version file in the current directory, and if it finds it, runs that version of bundle.

```
$ cd project-with-old-bundle-version
$ bundle --version
1.10.6
$ cd anywhere-else
$ bundle --version
1.11.2
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [the rbenv-gemset plugin](https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset). Since an older version of a gem in an rbenv gemset doesn't override a newer version in the default gemset, you'd need to install bundler for each project, which is rather cumbersome.

- Install the plugin (`cd ~/.rbenv/plugins; git clone git://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset.git`) OR, if you use homebrew, `brew install rbenv-gemset`
- `gem uninstall -xI bundler`
- For each project that can use bundler 1.11,

  - `cd` to the project
  - `echo bundler-1.11 > .rbenv-gemsets` ("bundler-1.11" is the name of the gemset)
- In one of those projects, `gem install bundler` to get the current version, 1.11.*
- For the project that needs bundler 1.10,

  - `cd` to the project
  - `echo bundler-1.10 > .rbenv-gemsets` ("bundler-1.10" is the name of the gemset)
  - `gem install bundler -v 1.10.6`

Comment: "Since an older version of a gem in an rbenv gemset doesn't override a newer version in the default gemset, you'd need to install bundler for each project, which is rather cumbersome." Ah yeah, that's pretty nonideal. Ideally, I'd just need to do something in this project's directory without having to do anything anywhere else...